# how can i filter data in minute wise or in hour wise or day wise or week wise if data is coming is every 30 seconds ,data is not there for some point

Tags: api, express, rest, amazon-dynamodb, backend

data is present is dynamodb and timestamp is integers and coming in the millisecond

I just wanted that how can I solve this, suppose the user ask for minutes wise data and average as an aggregation function for that minutes, and in every minute we are getting two data point but it may be possible there is no data for some point so for that case we have explicitly check and assign 0 for those points.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do functions such as aggregate on DynamoDB. You can get all of the items for the last `timeframe` so long as the `timeframe` is your sort-key.

### Item Collection

| PK | SK | Data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1674818685 | mydata |
| 123 | 1674818656 | mydata |
| 123 | 1674818632 | mydata |
| 123 | 1674818611 | mydata |
| 234 | 1674818600 | mydata |
| 234 | 1674818612 | mydata |
| 567 | 1674503932 | mydata |

Given the above schema, you want all of the data for item `123` for a 1 minute time frame, you can do so like below:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK = 123 AND SK BETWEEN time1 AND time2`

---

Note that you can only get the results are only for a given partition key, if you the results for every item in the table you would need a Global Secondary Index.

### All Items Using an Index

| GSI_PK | SK | Data | PL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1674818685 | mydata | 123 |
| 1 | 1674818656 | mydata | 123 |
| 1 | 1674818632 | mydata | 123 |
| 1 | 1674818611 | mydata | 123 |
| 1 | 1674818600 | mydata | 123 |
| 1 | 1674818612 | mydata | 123 |
| 1 | 1674503932 | mydata | 123 |

`SELECT * FROM mytable.myindex WHERE GSI_PK = 1 AND SK BETWEEN time1 AND time2`

Please note, having a single item value for your GSI PK will limit your write requests to 1000 WCU, if your application requires more you will need to [shard your index key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html).